# Why does my classpath only work with a colon on the end?

Tags: java, log4j, classpath

My app only starts logging to log4j if I put a : on the end off the classpath.  I already have the properties file and the jar in the classpath, so I'm not sure what's going on. What does ending the classpath with a colon even do?  The startup command thus becomes something like this:

```
java -cp path-to-log4j.properties:bunch:of:other:stuff: app
```

If I take that last colon off it stops logging, as if it can't find log4j.  My question is, what is that last colon actually doing, as in what directory is it adding to the classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually you should put the classpath in quotes -cp "path:path2".

EDIT: The colon might add the current directory.

EDIT2: One cannot add files (except jar files) directly to the classpath. Only directories. Read that today^^

Comment: I think I took the quotes out trying to find out what was wrong, I probably should put them back.  Looks like they're not important.  Hmm, I'll try taking the :[blank] out and put :${PWD} in and see if that works, that would confirm that...

Comment: Yep, that worked!  Thanks for that :)
No idea why I needed the pwd in the classpath when I had the full path to the log4j properties file and and the jar, but oh well!  Question answered, thanks! :D

Comment: that is because you cannot add files (except for jar files) to the classpath. Only directories!, also you do not need '${PWD}', a simple '.' is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Was surprised with similar situation:

Not working:

```
java -classpath swt.jar org.ivan.swt.SWTHelloWorld
```

Working:

```
java -classpath swt.jar: org.ivan.swt.SWTHelloWorld
```

Also working:

```
java -classpath :swt.jar org.ivan.swt.SWTHelloWorld
```

(note colon at the beginning and the end of the swt.jar)

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16) on Linux